# How to prevent values from rounding to zero javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two buttons, one that makes divs (of varying sizes) larger by a factor of 10 and one that makes them smaller by a factor of 10. After two clicks of the button that makes them smaller, the div is rounded to zero. No matter how many times you click the button that makes it larger it won't get larger because its multiplying the zero value. What is the standard way to fix this? This is necessary because in my application some of the divs are much much bigger than others, so while one div will be less than a pixel wide (and would then rightfully be invisible) others will be thousands of pixels wide.

UPDATE: My divs are actually circles representing planet diameters. I need these to be exact! If I click the smaller button 5 times, I want to be able to click the larger button 5 times and have it return to the exact diameter it was initially.

Also, it is probably not necessary to be able to make the divs smaller or larger an infinite number of times. What is the standard way to put a limit on it? Refer to my jsfiddle for an example of what I am trying to achieve. http://jsfiddle.net/dfjosh/vtxeD/12/

HTML

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="smaller">smaller</a>
<a href="javascript:;" class="larger">larger</a>
<div></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: cornflowerblue;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$('a').click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('smaller')) {
        var element = $('div');
        element.animate({
            'width' : element.width() * 0.1,
            'height' : element.height() * 0.1
        });
    } else if($(this).hasClass('larger')) {
        var element = $('div');
        element.animate({
            'width' : element.width() * 10,
            'height' : element.height() * 10
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you need to preserve aspect ratio?

Comment: yes, well, in reality my divs are circles achieved with a border-radius of 99999999%

Comment: @Jonathan - Great point. However I think that is a separate issue from reaching 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as it turns out, I am going to answer my own question. I appreciate all the help I received. I am certain the reason I didn't find an answer from you guys is because I didn't phrase the question right and I didn't give enough detail. Anyway, this is the solution to my problem:

I was originally scaling all my divs down by a factor of 1000 in css. That means, the div that (when scaled up) should have been 4879.4 px wide, I assigned a value of 4 in the css. Right away it lost 4 significant figures. What I ended up doing was storing the real (100% to scale) value in a javascript variable. That way, when I want to scale it, it uses the full value with all the significant digits. I can scale as far as I want down and up. And if I scale the 4px wide div down by a factor of 10, it rightfully dissapears, but comes right back when I scale back up.

Again, sorry I did such a bad job of asking the question. But I hope this answer helps anyone else wondering about this.

Answer (score 6):

Given that `0` evaluates as 'falsey' (or false-ish), you can use an `||` operator to pass `1` in the event that the `width()` or `height()` returns `0`:

```
var element = $('div');
element.animate({
    'width' : (element.width() || 1) * 10,
    'height' : (element.height() || 1) * 10
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dfjosh/vtxeD/12/).

Comment: +1 - Cool observation about using 0 as truthy. Although, the reason 0 returns is because it was set from javascript losing precision as the width got very small. Perhaps `0.1` would be a better choice than 1 to retain some of the "smallness".

Comment: @Steve - That is not the case. The size reaches "0.009374999999999994px" before it goes to 0.

Comment: Ok, I see where you're going. Here's more information to explain why that wouldn't be a complete solution to my problem: my divs are actually circles representing planet diameters. I need these to be exact! If I click the smaller button 5 times, I want to be able to click the larger button 5 times and have it return to the exact diameter it was initially. Your method would not do that

Comment: @Travis: thanks! I'd consider `0.1`, but my answer's more to demonstrate the *how*, I'm not sure exactly what the OP wants as regards to the maintenance of 'smallness,' so I'll leave it to him to adjust as required. Steve: the problem might well be with the CSS, but I'm not sure how to address that without using JavaScript.

Comment: @wetjosh: then you really need to add that information to the question.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the problem isn't so much the divs going to zero as getting them to come away from it again.

That's easily done:

```
'width' : (element.width() * 10) || 1
```

How that works: If `element.width()` returns `0`, of course `0 * 10` is also `0`. `0` is a falsey value, so the `||` uses `1` instead.

Or if you prefer:

```
'width' : (element.width() || 1) * 10
```

...which just kicks in more quickly. :-)

More: [*JavaScript's Curiously Powerful OR Operator (`||`)*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html)

Comment: should it not be (element.width() * 10) || 10?

Comment: @razzak: Depends on when you want it to kick in. I included a variant to kick in earlier, which is very similar to your comment, just in a different place. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to check if width has gone under 1 when making the div smaller. Add a restriction for height too if you want ratio preservation.

I'm adding another solution [here](http://jsbin.com/ofiQerE/1/edit).

And you won't be able to have exact return values using floats: 0.1. Since you're using decimal numbers, browsers treat rounding differently. For example, IE will only use a precision of tow decimals in CSS for JS calculated floats. Other browsers will use three decimals, but they will decide if the result will be used as is or altered, e.g. FF may turn a computed 13.205 into a used 13.207.

Best if you'll decide upon fixed hardcoded ranges for yourself. Or memorize new calculated widths and heights as you go and apply them when you go back. I imagine this would involve building two arrays, one for smaller, one for larger. Otherwise turn to canvas or svg.

Comment: +1 Point for the answer. I was going to suggest the same approach of setting a lower boundary and disable the reduce button when the limit is reached. Any other solution rounding to 1 or 0.1 or even 0 as done by the browser would introduce a discrepancy factor once the size increase button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you are looking for:

```
var element = $('div');
element.animate({
    'width' : Math.max(element.width() * 10), 50),
    'height' : Math.max(element.width() * 10), 50)
});
```

Comment: can you explain what that does?

Comment: if the width equal to 0 or less than 50 then the result will become 50, which i think is the default value you need looking at the css properties.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a check if it is still in some reasonable border, maybe like this:

```
'width' : ( element.width() > 0.1 ? element.width() * 0.1 : element.width() )
'height' : ( element.height() > 0.1 ? element.height() * 0.1 : element.height() )
```

This way it can actually get very small. But you should ask yourself which display is capable of displaying a pixel of a size of 0.25? At least one can assume that Apple's retina displays will be able to display a 0.5 pixel.

Answer (score 0):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/7hgWN/)***

One way to prevent it from reaching 0 is to adjust the height and width, check for 0, and then re-adjust back to a cached value if it does go to 0.

```
var w = element.width();
element.width(w*0.1);
var testWidth = element.width();
element.width(w);

if(testWidth == 0)return;

var h = element.height();
element.height(h*0.1);
var testHeight = element.height();
element.height(h);

if(testHeight == 0)return;
```